# Assign a version to default_url image in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am trying to add a version to the default_url image. I was trying something like this but it is not working due to which default_url image is smaller than other uploaded images. Any Idea where am I going wrong. The images which are uploaded, the URL for them appears like this

```
<img src="https://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/user/image/19/thumb_image_demo.jpg" class="main">
```

but for the default_url image, it appears like this

```
<img src="/fallback/avatar.png" class="main">
```

version is not attached to the image name. Maybe that's the issue. This is how I have defined in the uploader. Please suggest.

```
  def default_url
    "/fallback/images/" + [thumb_image, "avatar.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  version :thumb_image do
    process resize_to_fill: [365, 421]
  end
```

Comment: Hi. Please check if thumb_image is nil. That might lead to `default_url` returning the img src as "/fallback/avatar.png"

Comment: @AlokSwain How can I check that?